# Can't start React Native

Tags: android, react-native, adb

I'm on ubuntu 16.04. Trying to get started with React native, the official basic tutorial. I've initialized a sample project with react native cli but when I do `react-native run-android` it fails. if i try to use a real device I get `Could not get batched bridge`. I've googled for this issue but none of suggestions helped me. When I try to run it on Genymotion I get

```
ADB server didn't ACK
* failed to start daemon *
error: 
Starting the app (/home/yxfxmx/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb shell am    start -n com.test/.MainActivity...
error: no devices/emulators found
```

I've set Genymotion to use system SDK instead of its built-in one. Also, when I try to `adb start-server` while having Genymotion virtual device running I get

```
adb server is out of date.  killing...
cannot bind 'tcp:5037'
ADB server didn't ACK
```

If the virtual device is shut down I'm able to `adb start-server` or `adb-devices` ok. If my real phone is connected it can see it in `adb devices`. But if I have a virtual device running it fails. I also have Android studio installed, perhaps it may conflict?
If you have any suggestions plz post it.

Comment: r u using genymotion?

Comment: @MyMasterPeice yes. If you read the question you'll see that I've tried genymotion and experienced one issue, and tried a real phone and experienced another one

Answer (score 0):

> Solution 1 :

Basically genymotion uses different adb hence the solution could be use the adb you had used for android studio like below screenshot :

[image]

Browse the adb location in genymotion and set your custom adb and then restart your adb .

> Solution 2 :

Try running your application in other virtual emulators like bluestack

**Note : This issue is specific to genymotion emulator only**

Comment: as I've wrote in my question: `I've set Genymotion to use system SDK instead of its built-in one.`

Comment: and there are multiple device ur running one at a time?

Answer (score 0):

You may be having the problem if you have multiple versions of adb installed.

Type `whereis adb` and if you see it listed multiple times, one of which is you platform-tools location you could do with removing the one under /usr/bin using `sudo apt remove android-sdk*`.